# Vue.JS 2.0 slow when modifying unrelated data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Suppose I have an input field in Vue.JS that `v-model` bind to a String data property, and a long list of random numbers that are completely unrelated to that first String.

```
data: {
  input: "",
  randoms: []
}

<input type="text" v-model="input">
<p v-for="random in randoms" v-text="random"></p>
```

When I put both in the same Vue, I see a huge slowdown when typing in the input field, as it appears Vue is reevaluating the DOM for each list entry after every input event, although they really have nothing to do with each other.

https://jsfiddle.net/5jf3fmb8/2/

When I however move the `v-for` to a child component where I bind `randoms` to a prop, I experience no such slowdown

https://jsfiddle.net/j601cja8/1/

Is there a way I can achieve the performance of the second fiddle without using a child-component?

Comment: You could use debouncing, causing the `input` variable to be updated less often. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/5jf3fmb8/3/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way I can achieve the performance of the second fiddle without using a child-component?

#### Short answer

No.

#### Long answer

Whenever *any* dependency of the template changes, Vue has to re-run the render function for the entire component and diff the new virtualDOM against the new one. It can't do this for *this* or *that* part of the template only, and skip the rest. Therefore, each time the input value changes, the entire virutalDOM is re-rendered.

Since your v-for is producing quite a bit of elements, this can take a few 100ms, enough to be noticable when you type.

Extracting the heavy part of the template into its own component is in fact the "official" way to optimize that.

As Alex explained, v-model.lazy might improve the situation a bit, but does not fix the core of the issue.

Comment: Did not see this as I was typing the comment to Alex' answer, but I guess I arrived at the same conclusion then. So I will be using child components from now on then when you have lots of objects that do not frequently change (i.e. messages in an chat)

Answer (score 1):

Shortest, simplest answer: change `v-model` to `v-model.lazy`.

> When I put both in the same Vue, I see a huge slowdown when typing in the input field, as it appears Vue is reevaluating the DOM for each list entry after every input event, although they really have nothing to do with each other.

Note that the OnceFor sample *still* chugs like mad despite not actually being reactive any more. I don't understand Vue well enough to say if that's intentional or not.

```js
const Example = {
  data() { return { input: "", randoms: [] } },
  created() { this.newRandoms() },
  methods: {
    newRandoms() { this.randoms = Array(50000).fill().map(() => Math.random()) }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#vue-root",
  data(){ return {example: 'lazy-model'}},
  components: {
    LazyModel: {...Example, template: "#lazy-model"
    },
    OnceFor: {...Example, template: "#once-for"
    },
    InlineTemplate: {...Example, template: "#inline-template",
        components: {
          Welp: {
            props: ['randoms']
          }
        }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
button,
input,
div {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue-root">
  <span><button v-for="(component, name) in $options.components" @click="$set($data, 'example', name)">{{name}}</button></span>
  <component :is="example"></component>
</div>

<template id="lazy-model">
<div>
  <input type="text" v-model.lazy="input"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Regenerate" @click="newRandoms">
  <p v-for="random of randoms" v-text="random"></p>
</div>
</template>

<template id="once-for">
<div>
  <input type="text" v-model="input"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Regenerate" @click="newRandoms">
  <p v-for="random of randoms" v-text="random" v-once></p>
</div>
</template>

<template id="inline-template">
<div>
  <input type="text" v-model="input"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Regenerate" @click="newRandoms">
  <welp :randoms="randoms" inline-template>
    <div>
      <p v-for="(random, index) of randoms" :key="index"> {{index}}: {{random}} </p>
    </div>
  </welp>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! The lazy model and the debounce filter from the comment above really help improve the performance, however they do not completely eliminate the needless DOM changes, they just reduce them by a lot. (Compare console output of https://jsfiddle.net/j601cja8/2/ and https://jsfiddle.net/5jf3fmb8/4/). Therefor a dedicated child component still seems to be the best option. I also noticed the slowness even with the once-modifier, and I am not sure if the whole behaviour might not be bugged right now and I should file a report...